# Blob Datatype and Date Function

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

As I was going through the documentation of SQLite DB I found two things that don't digest to me:

1. I saw it got a [data type](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) `BLOB` . So any one please explain what is the real use of this data type?
2. Then I found out it got [Date And Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) , But i was not able use this in a successful way. i didn't grab it's main purpose also SQLITE doesn't got a datatype for date so how this will work with SQlite ??

So please somebody help to understand this.

Comment: BLOB = Binary Large Object (it can hold any binary data e.g. photos, etc)

Comment: `but i was not able use this in a success way`. Was there any error?

Comment: Are your two points related? i.e. Are you trying to perform Date functions on the Blob data type? Blob is a Binary Large Object, it can be used to store pretty much anything you like as Binary, a common use is to store files in their current format (rather than perhaps a string file path pointing to a file on disk). If your points are not related can you provide examples of the date functions not working as expected?

Comment: no, its,s not related .I just want to consume a general view about both concepts

Comment: @JJPA i doesn't have an idea about where to use this  Date And Time Functions and how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. BLOBs are designed to store binary data.
   They behave much like strings, but can store *any* data, such as zero bytes, or byte sequences that would not be valid UTF-8 data.

   You use BLOBs to store images, audio data, or just any kind of data that isn't a valid string.
2. As explained on the [data types page](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime), SQLite indeed does not have a separate date/time data type, but instead stores date/time values as strings or numbers.
   The data/time functions accept any string or number in such a format.

   To store a date in a SQLite database, use some SQLite function that returns a date (such as `date('now')` or `current_timestamp`), or just construct a string in the correct `yyyy-mm-dd...` format (or a day or seconds number).
   Such values can then be used with these date/time functions.

   If you don't ever want to use SQLite's built-in date/time functions, you also could use any other format to store dates/times.